# When do we need high memory and CPU in amazon AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scalability, amazon-rds

I understand that RDS instances will potentially require high disk space as the business grow. However, when does RDS require high memory? I thought high memory will be required in EC2 where a lot of business logic happens, but not necessarily the case in RDS. I understand i probably missing something here and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is that with more memory, more data, queries, and indexes can be cached in memory. If it can't do an operation in memory, it will do it on disk which is much slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a question of how databases use memory.

When a query engine is executing a statement, there are times when memory is used to store transient structures like spools, table variables, and so on. Under a lot of memory pressure, this stuff often ends up being written to tempdb (in the case of SQL server), which adds i/o overhead.

For a specific case, you really need to look at your own usage profiles to see if extra memory would help.